# Wireless USB adapter suddenly very slow

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, usb, dd-wrt

I have been using my wireless adapter fine for about 2-3 years on my Windows 7 PC, but a few days ago the internet became extremely sluggish, and no attempt to power on/off, re-plug, or fully re-install the drivers had any effect. It's a `Rosewill RNX-G1 802.11b/g` using Realtek drivers. I then tested the USB adapter by plugging it into a Windows 8 tablet (which also has built-in wireless capabilities) and performed a speed comparison of both wireless devices:

[image: speedtest results]
(download/upload) bandwidth:

- USB: 0.49/0.15 Mbps (14ms)
- Built-in: 14.52/2.24 Mbps (13ms)

As you can see, for some reason the USB adapter is about 30x slower download, and 15x slower upload, but they both have low pings and great signal strength (see 2nd image below) same location relative to router, same exact tablet. Is this related to degraded hardware in the USB adapter, or is it possibly a software issue related to the router (`Linksys WRTG54G V8` with `DD-WRT v24-sp2` firmware)? I checked to see if there were any QoS bandwidth limiters, but I've never enabled those and they are disabled.

[image: ipconfig results]